# Difference between HasEditorAccess and HasEditAccess?

Tags: episerver, access-rights

What is the difference between `EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.HasEditorAccess` and `EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.HasEditAccess`?

//Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in reflector, I see this:

```
private static readonly string _editorPath = UriSupport.ResolveUrlFromUIBySettings("Editor/");
private static readonly string _editPath = UriSupport.ResolveUrlFromUIBySettings("edit/");

...

public static bool HasEditAccess
{
  get
  {
    return Current.HasPathAccess(EditPath);
  }
}

public static bool HasEditorAccess
{
  get
  {
    return Current.HasPathAccess(EditorPath);
  }
}
```

_editorPath resolves to "/episerver/CMS/Editor/",
_editPath resolved to "/episerver/CMS/edit/"

It appears that HasEditorAccess is only used within the PropertyXhtmlStringControl for the OnPageEditControls so my guess would be that there are capabilities to give a user only on page edit rights and keep them out of the full editor.